# Node js router not handling delete

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express

my node js router it's not handling the delete method but all the others it's handling well (GET, POST, UPDATE etc etc) but the delete does not reach the router and i can't figure why.

The ajax it's doing the request correctly at least it seems to be doing it.

**ajax request:**

```
function ajaxHelper(url, onSuccessArray, onErrorArray, onFinishArray, verb, data) {
    verb = verb || "GET";
    document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "block";
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open(verb, url);
    xhr.responseType = "json";
    xhr.addEventListener("load", function () {
        document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "none";
        let status = this.status;
        if (status === 200) {

            if (onSuccessArray) {

                onSuccessArray.reverse();
                onSuccessArray.forEach(function (onSuccess) {

                    onSuccess && onSuccess(xhr.response)
                });
            }
        } else {

            if (onErrorArray) {

                onErrorArray.reverse();
                onErrorArray.forEach(function (onErrorCallback) {

                    onErrorCallback && onErrorCallback(status, xhr.response);
                })
            }
        }
        if (onFinishArray) {

            onFinishArray.reverse();
            onFinishArray.forEach(function (onFinishCallback) {

                onFinishCallback && onFinishCallback(status);
            })
        }
    });
    if (data) {

        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
        xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data));
    } else {

        xhr.send();
    }
}

function removePlayer(onSuccessArray, onErrorArray, onFinishArray, data) {

    ajaxHelper("/players/delete-player", onSuccessArray, onErrorArray, onFinishArray, "DELETE", data);
}
```

**app.js**

```
let express = require('express');
let path = require('path');
let favicon = require('serve-favicon');
let logger = require('morgan');
let cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
let bodyParser = require('body-parser');

let index = require('./routes/index');
let cups = require('./routes/route-cup');
let leagues = require('./routes/route-league');
let players = require('./routes/route-player');
let teams = require('./routes/route-team');

let app = express();

app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', '/images/favicon.png')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(cookieParser());


app.use('/cups', cups);
app.use('/leagues', leagues);
app.use('/players', players);
app.use('/teams', teams);
app.use(express.static("public", {
    "index": "index.html"
}));

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    let err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    // set locals, only providing error in development
    res.locals.message = err.message;
    res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

    // render the error page
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

**router:**

```
let express = require('express');
let router = express.Router();
let mysql = require("mysql");
let sqlHelper = require("../scripts/sql-helper");

router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    let sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + dbName + ".player;";
    sqlHelper.executeSql(res, sqlQuery, function (rows, fields) {

        res.json(rows);
    })
});

router.get('/free-players', function (req, res, next) {
    let sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + dbName + ".player WHERE 'teamName' <> ''";
    sqlHelper.executeSql(res, sqlQuery, function (rows, fields) {

        res.json(rows);
    })
});

router.post('/submit-player', function (req, res, next) {
    let keys = objectHelper.getObjectKeys(req.body);
    let values = objectHelper.getObjectValues(req.body);
    let placeHolders = new Array(keys.length).fill("?");
    let sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO " + dbName + ".`player` (" + keys.toString() + ") VALUES (" + placeHolders.toString() + ")";

    sqlQuery = mysql.format(sqlQuery, values);
    sqlHelper.executeSql(res, sqlQuery, function (rows, fields) {

        res.json(rows);
    });
});

router.put('/update-player', function (req, res, next) {
    let keys = objectHelper.getObjectKeys(req.body);
    let values = objectHelper.getObjectValues(req.body);
    let sqlQuery = "UPDATE " + dbName + ".`player` SET ";
    let valuePair = [];
    keys.forEach(function (key, index) {
        if (values[index] !== null) {

            valuePair.push(key + "=" + "'" + values[index] + "'");
        } else {

            valuePair.push(key + "=" + values[index]);
        }
    });
    sqlQuery = sqlQuery + valuePair.toString() + " WHERE " + valuePair[0];
    sqlHelper.executeSql(res, sqlQuery, function (rows, fields) {

        res.json(rows);
    });
});

router.delete('/delete-player', function (req, res, next) {
    let sqlQuery = "DELETE " + dbName + ".`player` WHERE id=" + req.body;
    sqlHelper.executeSql(res, sqlQuery, function (rows, fields) {

        res.json(rows);
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

**Server log:**

```
GET /players 304 53.636 ms - -
GET /teams 304 46.161 ms - -
GET /players 304 13.676 ms - -
DELETE /players/delete-player 400 3059.064 ms - 1397
Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided.
```

Comment: Please learn about SQL injection...

Comment: This is only a test app for learning purposes i know it's vulnerable to sql injection

Comment: Famous last words ;D Anyway, if the request doesn't reach the handler, what is the response that the server sends back?

Comment: i've added to the question, thanks in advance

Comment: P.S. Use `/players/12` instead `players/12/"action"-player` because method define "action".

Comment: 400 means "Bad Request". Typically, you don't send a body with `DELETE` requests, but Express doesn't really care, so not sure where that 400 is coming from. The second error is caused by not specifying a template engine and trying to render a template anyway (in the error handler).

Comment: Verify that you send `delete` request. Also you can print `req.method` inside error handler to debug.

Comment: @AikonMogwai and robertklep thank you! you are both right the delete doesn't need any data(body) it's was a mistake from copy paste and it will do it by queryString. If you please give the answer

Comment: @robertklep and AikonMogwai thank you! you are both right the delete doesn't need any data(body) it's was a mistake from copy paste and it will do it by queryString. If you please give the answer

Answer (score 2):

You're getting a 400 response (*"Bad Request"*) because you're most likely sending a (JSON-encoded) *string* to the backend.

However, when using `application/json`, the data that you send should be either a (JSON-encoded) object, or an array, but not a string. That's why the server returns a 400.

A more typical solution would be to pass the property to delete in the URL itself:

```
DELETE /players/delete-player/jack
```

You would use a route like this:

```
router.delete('/delete-player/:name', ...)
```

And access the name as `req.params.name` (which would equal *"jack"* in this example).

More info on route parameters here: http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-parameters